# Returning specific field from a matching record

Tags: ms-access, select, excel, ms-access-2007, vba

I'm still a newbie at Access 2007, but I feel I am missing a understanding of a concept, when it comes to using user input from an unbound text box.

I'm trying to have the user input the record number (i.e. A12) and return another field in the matching record (such as the record status like "Opened")

I'm fiddling with DLookup to see if it will work through that method but no luck yet. 
I may look into SELECT - SQL, but I haven't used that function yet and not sure if that will give me the result I'm looking for.

If this is something elementary to access programming (or databases in general), please let me know where I can read up on this. 
I am currently using the MSDN website, but examples go much further to play with.

**Edit:**
My DLookup so far, which happens after update from user on Text12

```
Me.Text14.Value = DLookup("[RecordStatus]", "Orders", Text12.Value)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look closer at the third option (*Criteria*) in your `DLookup()` expression.  You gave it only `Text12.Value`, which I assume is a string value like "A12".

The *Criteria* parameter should be like a `WHERE` clause in a query, without the word `WHERE`.  IOW, some field's value = "A12". If that field is named "record_id", try this:

```
DLookup("RecordStatus", "Orders", "record_id = '" & Me.Text12 & "'")
```

Comment: The change to the criteria worked. I thought it functioned a little bit differently, but thank you for showing me otherwise!